# Sub aggregations in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to work out with Elasticsearch aggregations!
I want to fetch the users that have same operations ID anf for each ID also match two other fields!
So it's like aggregations upon aggregations!
I am not understanding how to go about it!
Can someone help with structuring it??

Comment: Please show a few sample documents and the results you'd like to get.

Answer (score 10):

From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html):

> Bucketing aggregations can have sub-aggregations (bucketing or metric). The sub-aggregations will be computed for the buckets which their parent aggregation generates. There is no hard limit on the level/depth of nested aggregations (one can nest an aggregation under a "parent" aggregation, which is itself a sub-aggregation of another higher-level aggregation).

You should also check out the more verbose [Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html).

There you can find complete examples, such as the following which is provided in the chapter ["Aggregations » Aggregation Test-Drive » Adding a Metric to the Mix"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_adding_a_metric_to_the_mix.html):

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search
{
   "size" : 0,
   "aggs": {
      "colors": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "color"
         },
         "aggs": { 
            "avg_price": { 
               "avg": {
                  "field": "price" 
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This aggregation is nesting the `avg` metric inside the `terms` bucket, effectively generating an average for each color (compare [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_adding_a_metric_to_the_mix.html)).